# Why does Firewall Prevent Access to Domain Controller GPMC?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, windows-firewall

I have 2 Windows Server 2008 R2.
Both servers are Domain Controllers.

Currently the security policy is to disable Windows Firewall but set certain firewall rules. Previously I have enabled the firewall and was able to edit the GPO's Windows Firewall Rules. Recently when I turn the firewall off and launch the Group Policy Management, the program then starts crashing. It then says it is unable to access the domain controller. They both do the same thing. I also then chose the itself as the domain controller to refer to and it says it can't reach it.

If I turn the firewall back on and try to go to GPMC on it I can get it but I cannot edit the firewall. It gives the 0x6d9 error.

So it seems I am in a catch 22. Why can I not edit my Group Policy Firewall Settings with the Firewall actually on? When it is **THE FIREWALL IS ON** I cannot ping the server from the other until I turn it off. But it is getting all the firewall allowance rules and what not. Firewall GPO is set to default settings so there is no reason it should be preventing me from getting any information.

Group Policy Client is Running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabled the firewall on one domain controller and it lost connection to itself as a domain controller. Pointed it at the other domain controller and allowed all required firewall rules to allow network connections and now I can edit firewall settings on all systems without a problem. This issue was confusing when you have to point to each other to get it to work in the first place but now all is well.